# Slow associations in SequelizeJS

Tags: mysql, node.js, postgresql, sequelize.js

I am trying to diagnose the cause of some slow downs in my Express app which is using SequlizeJS as the ORM. I have a model that has a 2x hasMany & a hasOne relation with 2 other models:

**Update**: I've made the associations within the define call using the classMethods#associate function.

```
// Model1
classMethods: {
    associate: function(models) {
        Model1.hasMany(models.Model2);
        Model1.hasMany(models.Model3);
        Model1.hasOne(models.Model2, {as: 'next', foreignKey: 'model2_next'});
    }
}

// Model2
classMethods: {
    associate: function(models) {
        Model2.belongsTo(models.Model1, {foreignKey: 'model2_next'});
    }
}
```

if I query them in the following manner:

```
db.Model1.find({
    where: { /* Simple where statement */ },
    include: [
        db.Model2,
        db.Model3,
        { model: db.Model2, as: 'next' },
    ]
}).complete(function(err, data) {
    res.json(data);
});
```

It can take between 8-12seconds to respond. However, if I query Model2 separately and merge them manually using the async & lodash libraries:

```
async.parallel({
    model2: function(callback) {
        db.Model2.findAll({
            where: { /* Simple where statement */ }
        }).complete(callback)
    },
    model1: function(callback) {
        db.Model1.find({
            where: { /* Simple where statement */ },
            include: [
                db.Model3,
                { model: db.Model2, as: 'next' },
            ]
        }).complete(callback);
    }
}, function(err, data) {
    var response = data.model1.values;
    response.Model2 = data.model2.map(function(Model2){ return Model2.values });

    res.json(response);
})
```

it takes between 60-100ms.

I've tried switching from MySQL to PostgreSQL and whilst PostgreSQL was fractionally faster, it was a matter of 2-3%!

What is causing Sequelize to take so much longer than the split query and is there a way I can speed this up?

Comment: How you associated objects?
Explain sql query, check MYSQL use an index?

Comment: @ahiipsa Thanks, I've updated the question with the association details. I'll dig through the logs and see if I can pull out the relevant SQL queries asap. With regards to indexes; Sequelize has generated a Model1Id in the Model2 table - should I index this?

Comment: i add answer about index

Comment: How many rows in tables? Describe your Model, what is it? And why are they related?  maybe problem in database design.

Comment: NOTE: you can use `{ separate: true }` in your `include` array and sequelize will perform separate queries and join the data in-memory for you.

Answer (score 20):

Sequelize slows down when you add :M relations to your include.
:M relations result in duplicate rows in your sql result, so we have to spend time deduplicating that and parsing it into models.

For optimal performance you could leave your :1 relations in your include but do the :M in seperate queries.

Of course the query itself could also be slow, but most likely it's the result of Sequelize overhead - Try running the query directly on the database.

(Disclaimer: Sequelize core developer)

What version are you running on? The initial number you reported sounds high, but we have heard of those numbers before we did some optimizations, try testing against the latest git master.

We're always working on optimizing the code for these scenarios, but deduplicating 20.000 rows to 5.000 rows will always require some cpu cycles.

Comment: Hi @mick-hansen thanks for taking the time... I see your activity on the issue tracker :) As suggested in my question I have now segmented the queries and am manually merging the data back together. I'm using version 1.7, will I been in for a world of hurt upgrading to 2.0 (Unstable)?

Comment: There are breaks in upgrading to 2.0, they are breaks for the better though. Both performance and API wise.

Comment: Ok, gonna try the solution from @ahiipsa below and may try upgrading too, is there an upgrade guide or changelog i can refer to?

Comment: Cheers mick, appears to be in obvious place haha - I totally failed at searching for it hehe :P

Comment: @MickHansen thanks for the info. After running the queries generated in the debugger I can see exactly how this is happening. In my case, a query returns about 3,000 records in 60ms but takes another 1,000ms to de-dupe them. Is separating out my :M associations into a second query still the recommended approach?

Comment: @CharlieSchliesser If they are 1:M you can now use `seperate: true`

Comment: Thanks! I had split the queries last night by hand and sped it up by 50%. Just tried the previous code with `separate: true` operators on the `include`'s and it has the same speed advantage. Appreciate the quick response.

Answer (score 13):

For your `hasMany` includes (and after proper indexing), consider adding `separate: true,`.

It basically executes `include` blocks in parallel, instead of sequentially.

I had a query that went from 10 seconds to less than 200 miliseconds after that:

```js
include: [
    {
        model: MyModel,
        as: 'myModels',
        separate: true, // does magic; only with .hasMany associations
    },
]
```

Documentation: https://sequelize.org/api/v7/interfaces/includeoptions#separate

Answer (score 2):

in your model association, sequelizejs don't create index

add [{foreignKeyConstraint: true}](http://sequelizejs.com/docs/latest/associations#foreign-keys) to all association.

```
Model1.hasMany(models.Model2, {foreignKeyConstraint: true});
Model1.hasMany(models.Model3, {foreignKeyConstraint: true});
Model1.hasOne(models.Model2, {as: 'next', foreignKey: 'model2_next', foreignKeyConstraint: true});
Model2.belongsTo(models.Model1, {foreignKey: 'model2_next', foreignKeyConstraint: true});
```

Comment: Hi @ahiipsa, thanks for your answer... this has improved performance but unfortunately it's still around 4-5secs per query.

Comment: Add to third association too. how meny rows in tables?