# What does 'separate' in sequelize mean?

Tags: sequelize.js

I searched in the official docs of sequelize and couldn't find any entry about '`separate`'.https://readthedocs.org/search/?q=separate

I also searched on google but in vain.

```
  db.fooTable.find({
        where: {
            id: id
        },
        include: [{
            model: db.barTable1,
            separate: true
        }, {
            model: db.barTable2,
            separate: true
        }, {
            model: db.barTable3,
            separate: true
        }]
    })
```

To find out what it means, I set '`separate`' to false, but the result of the query were the same as to when I put '`true`' instead.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

I found this in the [current code](https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/blob/v3.23.3/lib/model.js#L1306):

> If true, runs a separate query to fetch the associated instances, only supported for hasMany associations

To elaborate: by default, to retrieve the related model instance, Sequelize will use a SQL JOIN. By enabling `separate`, Sequelize will perform a separate query for each of the associated models, and join the resulting documents in code (instead of letting the database perform the join).

Assume I have `Product` model with a `hasMany` association to the `Tag` model (*"a product can have many tags associated with it"*).

Here's the "regular" query:

```
SELECT
  `product`.`id`,
  `product`.`title`,
  `tags`.`id` AS `tags.id`,
  `tags`.`name` AS `tags.name`,
  `tags`.`productId` AS `tags.productId`
FROM `products` AS `product`
LEFT OUTER JOIN `tags` AS `tags`
ON 
  `product`.`id` = `tags`.`productId`;
```

Here are the `separate : true` queries:

```
SELECT 
  `product`.`id`,
  `product`.`title`
FROM `products` AS `product`;

SELECT
  `id`,
  `name`,
  `productId`
FROM `tags` AS `tag`
WHERE 
  `tag`.`productId` IN (1);
```

Comment: How can this query help us get products with some specified tags as parameters ?

Comment: What's the benefit? From what you've written, I can only see the downside of performance-cost because it gets partially executed on code-side instead of inside the database!?

Comment: @C4d see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56682386/893780) for a possible reason for its existence.

Comment: @robertklep Thanks. What a coincidence that I ran into another issue yesterday. I had so many joins that the aliases got cutted of because of a character limitation of max 63. "separate" is kinda solving this too (apart from the quite new option "minifyAliases").

Comment: @C4d Sequelize has the big issue of doing a huge JOIN of everything, you can easily start including too many things, and then be querying thousands or rows when you just needed a few. Separate allows to get the same include-able benefits but with less multiplicity.

Answer (score 10):

Additional to @robertklep response:

As you know now it separates an **otherwise** joined query.

This means that it would be more performant in some situations where you have many joins and nested joins (can have a huge impact in some). Nested joins make Sequelize take more time in a single big query than running multiple small ones.  The problem is pointed out as a deduplication operation:

See here:
[Slow associations in SequelizeJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23014902/slow-associations-in-sequelizejs)