# Very bad performance using sequelize.js and mysql

Tags: javascript, mysql, sequelize.js

I am developing a node backend with the feathers.js framework and sequelize.js as database adatper.

Overall I noticed a very bad performance when querying data from the backend. The example with the worst performance constitutes the querying of a table with ~25 columns and 10.000 entries. I can query every entry in this table using mysql workbench in 0.013s + 0.352s fetch time (network). When querying the same query using sequelize, it takes an average of 2.5 seconds (isolated request) for the query to complete. The feathers-sequelize package is used to automatically generate the services including database requests via command line.

- node v8.10.0
- feathers-sequelize v3.1.3
- sequelize v4.42
- mysql-server v5.6

I already tried to increase the connection pool sequelize is able to use without success.

I am querying without any additional parameters or joins in my test example.

`app.service(service_name).find();`

which when debugging results in the sequelize call

`sequelize.models.service_name.findAll();`

I realize the transformation from the binary data from the database into JSON takes some time, but I think it should be possible to perform this request within 0.4s.

Comment: Do you measure the whole request or just the query time?

Comment: Try enable logging and you should be able to get an idea of the query time, you can also set `raw: true` to not parse the results to Instances: `sequelize.models.service_name.findAll({ logging: true, raw: true );`

Comment: I was measuring the whole request in the backend compared to the query itself in mysql workbench

@doublesharp I was using the same SQL statements for the query, which I got from enabled logging. I was also using raw query, which was not resulting in a performance boost

Comment: The last part of the logging is the execution time of the statement. You need to figure out which part is slow to debug further.

Answer (score 2):

I faced some performance issues with a table of 20000 records, but I would not say it is solely related to Sequelize. I could list the measures that helped me improve the performance.

1. Sequelize `separate: true` in HasMany includes (See this thread for more info: [What does 'separate' in sequelize mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37964763/what-does-separate-in-sequelize-mean))
2. Do not prefix `%` in wildcard searches

`SELECT * FROM players WHERE first_name LIKE "JOHN%";`

is much faster than

`SELECT * FROM players WHERE first_name LIKE "%JOHN%";`

(This website explains how MySQL https://use-the-index-luke.com/sql/where-clause/searching-for-ranges/like-performance-tuning)

3. Create Indexes for frequently used attributes in `WHERE` conditions as well as in the `ORDER` clause

`CREATE INDEX player_search_index ON player (first_name, last_name, rank)`