# Sequelize high memory usage with n:m assosiations

Tags: node.js, express, sequelize.js, out-of-memory

my setup is sequelize.js with node.js and express.js. I'm having an model called 'Room'. This model has some n:m associations. Since i filter my data acording to the association data, every time i getting all the Rooms, I have to include all associations.

```
Room.findAll({
    where: whereCondition,
    include: ['purposes', 'prices', 'furnishing', 'technic', 'floor']
}).then(data => {
  res.send(data);
});
```

An example how an association is setup:

```
// room <-> technic m:n
db.room.belongsToMany(db.technic, {
  as: "technic",
  through: "room_technic",
  foreignKey: "roomId",
  otherKey: "technicId"
});
db.technic.belongsToMany(db.room, {
  as: "rooms",
  through: "room_technic",
  foreignKey: "technicId",
  otherKey: "roomId"
});
```

This leads to a big query. I found an quite old answer, about memory problems with one big query: https://stackoverflow.com/a/23081751/2834550
The suggestion was to split up the query to have multiple ones.

So, I'm theoratically asking how to split it up?

And is it still the best way to overcome the bad memory performance?

Thanks,
Luc

Comment: I guess you are talking about cpu cycles? And round trip time? How is that affecting the memory. 
How many rooms do you have?

Comment: @iwaduarte this app is hosted on heroku and the metrics are telling me, that it exceeds the 512MB ram limit. I only have about 90 rooms, but running this query will lead to an result with 19200 entries.

Comment: The question is. 1) Do you need all attributes of those includes? 2) Do you need them all in one go? 3)Still seems to me that something else could be affecting performance what is your setup in the heroku environment? Which database are you using? And how long it takes to the query to be fetched?

Comment: @iwaduarte thanks for your reply. Well the problem is, i need all attributes for filtering. For showing the rooms to the user, they are not needed at first. So I splitted up the query into small ones, where each of them returns the filtered rooms and then I return all rooms with those ids. Don't know if this is "good", but the performance is significant better! I guess i can live with it.

Comment: @iwaduarte 3) what you men exactly with setup? I'm using a postgresql db.

Comment: I would check if I would be able to expand the limits of memory/cpu on the "container" that you are using.
I would also increase the numbers of connections of sequelize  and I would try to see if it is slow because of deduplication itself or if it is taking to long to get the data.
I would let the filters with database and index where possible.
To break include is advisable to use {separate: true} see here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37964763/what-does-separate-in-sequelize-mean

Comment: thanks. As i can see, using separate: true doesn't work with 'belongsToMany' (https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/issues/4376) . As for the resources, with my plan (basic) it seems, without spending money adding up memory/cpu isn't an option for me. For the db connection the same: https://help.heroku.com/PPL2UUGB/why-can-t-we-increase-database-connection-limits-on-postgres

Answer (score 0):

One way to do it is to use pagination/limiting:
[Doc link](https://sequelize.org/v5/manual/querying.html#pagination---limiting)

A good practice is to have a default pagination on your REST API resources, and an optional query string parameters of LIMIT and SKIP